# Drupal 7 multi-site install is half working--What's the next thing to check with a View SQL error?

Tags: views, multi-sites

Multi-site Drupal 7 and Draggableviews module is giving me heck. I've uninstalled every module and re-enabled the absolute minimum in a sub-site (call this site "wiskey") of my multi-site installation. A search for similar "unknown column" errors frequently pointed to References module. I updated with drush upc.

Since this is a multi-site, I created a Draggableviews test View in the default site (call this site "alpha") and this works, and drags my table like a champ. Which tells me its a problem with the 'w-site' and there's nothing wrong with the Drupal, Views, or Draggableviews modules.

I ran a diff on drush pml of both sub-sites until they were identical. Enabled Seven theme. I re-made the original view. Cleared the Views cache. But, I'm still getting this error,

```
SQLSTATE [42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'draggableviews_structure.weight' in 'field list'.
```

### What next?

This= Drupal 7 (recently updated). MySQL. Only one admin user (I checked all the admin/owner permissions to be sure).

Comment: Did you run `drush updb` for the sub-site ?

Comment: I did after you mentioned it:) Actually, drush reminded me to updb for a-site. I didn't think of it for w-site. Unfortunately, this has not solved the problem. I remade the view's drag-page again (one page for end user and other for admin) after the updb. As soon as I add the Sort Criteria: Draggableviews the SQL error shows up in preview...

Comment: Then your problem probably belongs in DV issue queue and/or multisite support page, wherever it may be. Or perhaps you could first search in the Views issue queue. Anyway, this is as far as my help goes. Sorry.

Comment: You agree then I've met due diligence for Issue report? haha